# Eclipse Android Exception : Unhandled event loop exception No more handles

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android programming. Here is my problem. i get this exception frequently even in all newly created project files. I captured that Exception.
Actually i can work with android although i have this error and also able to run the emulator after pressing "no" to the second window. This happens only when i switch between package Explorer and java code. not in xml view. 
i want to know whether i can ignore this exception and continue or not.
Thanks

[image: Unhandled event loop[ exception]

when pressing ok i got this

[image]

```
enter code here

Here is my error log 

    !SESSION 2013-11-06 12:01:49.217 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
    java.version=1.7.0_03
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    ---
    ---
    ---
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-11-06 13:30:18.160
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$15(WorkbenchPage.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4655)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Does this issue reoccurs after restarting Eclipse.?

Comment: i don't want to have any code to get this error. even when i drag and drop button and change the text and run it. After sometime i get this exception. By that time i have already viewed it in the emulator. and then i can close the exception and continue it. Thanks

Comment: Yes after sometime this reoccur again. any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok finally even though its some time i like to share this. i found a solution for this. In my case i was using separate eclipse to work with android. Finally i downloaded the Android ADT bundle(which includes Eclipse by default) and now everything works fine for me. Glad if anyone get help from this comment.